# wilcox_effsize() returns different (much higher) values than manual calculation

Tags: r, pairwise.wilcox.test

I want to calculate the effect size for a number of pairwise comparisons in R. The data is paired: the df consists of 115 respondents who each rated 7 entities on a scale of 1-4. I transformed the df to the melted (long) format (here an imaginary example):

```
respondent  entity  rating
1            1         2
1            2         4
1            3         1
1            4         3
1            5         4
1            6         3
1            7         4
2            1         3
2            2         3
2            3         2
2            4         4
2            5         1
2            6         3
2            7         2
.......
```

The goal is to compare the rating of each of the 7 entities to the other 6. I've already conducted pairwise comparisons using `pairwise.wilcox.test(data$rating, data$entity, p.adjust.method = "holm", exact = FALSE, paired = TRUE)`, which worked fine. I then wanted to calculate the effect size of each comparison using `wilcox_effsize()`:

```
df=data %>% wilcox_effsize(rating~entity, paired = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame())
```

Since I wasn't quite sure whether I was using this function correctly, I compared the results to the effect sizes which I calculated 'manually' using the function provided by Field et al. (2012, p. 665):

```
rFromWilcox<-function(wilcoxModel, N){
  z<- qnorm(wilcoxModel$p.value/2)
  r<- z/ sqrt(N)
  cat(wilcoxModel$data.name, "Effect Size, r = ", r)
}
```

(I entered 230 as the N, since 115*2 = 230, and I computed several "wilcoxModels" using the data in wide format and the following code; I then entered each model into the function:

```
model_entity1vs2 = wilcox.test(data$rating_ent1, data$rating_ent2, paired = TRUE, exact = FALSE)
```

Data in wide format:

```
respondent  rating_ent1 rating_ent2 rating_ent3 .......
    1            1         2           3
    2            2         4           4
    3            3         1           2
    4            4         3           1
    5            4         4           2
    6            2         3           1
    ....         ....      ...         ...  
   115           1         3           2
```

And then for each comparison:

```
rFromWilcox(model_entity1vs2, 230)
```

I then noticed that the effect sizes which I calculated manually were substantially smaller than the ones in the output of `wilcox_effsize()` (e.g. *r* = 0.35 vs. *r* = 0.52), so something must be wrong. I first thought that the function might have a problem with the long format and might have misread the sample size, but the output gives n1 = 115 and n2 = 115, so that seems to be in order:

```
   y    group 1     group 2     effsize   n1  n2    magnitude
rating  entity1     entity2     0.52345   115 115   large
rating  entity1     entity3     0.51847   115 115   large
rating  entity1     entity4     0.38759   115 115   moderate
...
```

Something is clearly wrong but I'm not sure what... Did I make a mistake in my code when using
`wilcox_effsize()` for paired data?

Comment: Why did you use 115*2? If you read the documentation for `wilcox_effsize`, it defines `N` as the total number of pairs for paired samples test. The number of pairs is 115 here, I think. In your calculation, it looks like you've defined `N` differently.

Comment: I used 115*2 not for wilcox_effsize but for the function provided by Field et al., i.e. for rFromWilcox(). Field et al. define N as the number of observations - on p. 673 they discuss an example and state "... we had 20 observations (although we only used 10 people and tested them twice, it is the number of observations, not the number of people, that is important here)." So this function takes the number of respondents * 2 (because we have two values for each respondent...). (This is the book btw: https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/discovering-statistics-using-r/book236067)